# ERROR: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List?' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

(Edit)

I saved the image data of the Uint8List type in the post model and saved at my local storage. And use fromJson() to import saved data back to the post model.
However, the following error occurs in the thumbimage = json[POST_THUMBIMAGE];

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List?'
```

Why do these errors occur and how can it be solved?

My model class is as follows

```
class PostModel {
  late String category;
  late String title;
  Uint8List? thumbImage;


  PostModel({
    required this.category, 
    required this.title,
    this.thumbImage,
  });

  // error!
  PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    category = json[POST_CATEGORY] ?? "";
    title = json[POST_TITLE] ?? "";
    thumbImage = json[POST_THUMBIMAGE];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map[POST_CATEGORY] = category;
    map[POST_TITLE] = title;
    map[POST_THUMBIMAGE] = thumbImage;

    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image list as a List < Uint8List >?.
And you try to put a List < Dynamic> inside then.

change the image list to Dynamic.

```
List<dynamic>? images;
```

Comment: Hello.

I edited it <dynamic> and corrected my question after the test.
I have a problem output images using Image.memory() so could you tell me about this?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ExtendedImage.memory(
                context.read<PostProvider>().posts[index].images![0]),


Error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055981/type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-uint8list